# Apache Chainsaw successor?

Tags: logging, log4j, apache-chainsaw

It looks like the development on [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) has stopped 4 years ago (last development build dated 2006-03-02)...

Anyone knows of a replacement tool providing the same functionality, but with  more up to date releases?

Comment: There has been recent discussion on the log4j lists about an upcoming release of Chainsaw.

Comment: Upcoming release soon - see answer below.

Comment: Updated version of Chainsaw has been released - see https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/

Answer (score 18):

I'm developing [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/). It's on Apache license and highly active. It has some interesting new features like automatic log events marking, highlighting part of log message, human friendly formatting soap messages and others.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer

Answer (score 8):

Log4j is [dead in the water](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) anyway. You might be better served by moving to [SLF4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) and [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). Then, you can use [Lilith](http://lilith.huxhorn.de/) to view your logs.

Comment: Using logback pages to argue that log4j is dead in the water, is like using Microsoft pages to argue that Linux is dead in the water.  I trust you know the history of logback?

Comment: True, that page should have been my argument to move away from log4j. The main log4j page (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) could be an argument for log4j being dead in the water. "Dead in the water" is probably also a poor choice of words. "Mature" is probably more correct, as used on the log4j site.

Comment: log4j 1.x is a 'mature' technology, but work is proceeding on log4j 2.0 at a rapid pace at the moment.

See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2

Comment: Thorbjørn, the analogy would be relevant if Bill Gates had written  Linux, which of course he did not.

Comment: Lilith looks like it works with log4j...

Comment: Why is it dead? There's an adapter from log4j to slf4j.

Answer (score 8):

Massive updates coming to Chainsaw..see screenshots here or pull it down via svn + maven & give it a spin..

Screenshots show it tailing Android, palm logs, regular text log files, filtering, colorizing & search..

http://www.flickr.com/photos/79551761@N00/

And release notes in svn here: 
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/chainsaw/trunk/src/main/resources/org/apache/log4j/chainsaw/help/release-notes.html?revision=946898&view=co

Comment: any update? It's more than a year later and I cannot find any release... Thanks.

Comment: There is a developer snapshot (Mac DMG and zip for windows and linux) available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: @Scott The v2.1 snapshot includes the delta millisecond column that was not available in the old release still referenced at [logging.apache.org/chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/download.html). Thanks for the mentioning the snapshot!

Answer (score 3):

Haven't use this yet, but I like the concepts.

http://logio.org/

Answer (score 2):

Our product [SmartInspect](https://www.gurock.com/smartinspect) comes with a graphical log analysis and viewer tool. You can also integrate SmartInspect with log4j:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gurock.com](http://www.gurock.com/images/feature/smartinspect-screenshot-home.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Someone maintains the latest developer builds for Windows, Linux, and OS X here:

https://people.apache.org/~sdeboy/

Presumably they are built from this source code, but I am not sure:

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/chainsaw/trunk/src/